# How to clone Canvas Control wpf?

Tags: wpf, canvas, mvvm, rotatetransform, rendertransform

Currently I am working on desktop application. In which,I am printing Canvas Control using PrintVisual Method of print dialog. I am passing canvas From View to view model as Command Parameter.
In view Model i am performing Rotate Transform on Canvas(I want to print my content by 180degree rotation).But i want it just in my View Model not in view 
Currently i am facing a problem is that my canvas control also rotate in view which i don't want.
Please help me to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your transformations on a new `Canvas` with a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) of your original `Canvas` as `Background`.

PS: There is a [VisualBrush constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602558.aspx) that accepts a `Visual`.

EDIT

This should give you an idea:

```
Canvas printCanvas = new Canvas();
printCanvas.Background = new VisualBrush(yourOriginalCanvas);
printCanvas.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(180);
```

Comment: Can u explain how can i do it with VisualBrush because i m confused to use viewbox or viewport @taras

Answer (score 0):

I think you could work around with PrintDialogs PrintTicket.PageOrientation property it takes such enum:

- Landscape
- Portrait  (default)
- ReverseLandscape
- ReversePortrait
- Unknown

Like so:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.ReversePortrait;
```